# Wordpress: How to deregister CSS file?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to deregister CSS files from my Wordpress site, but it doesn't work. I'm using Avada template, I've added this code to "functions.php":

```
function remove_unwanted_css(){
    wp_deregister_style('dashicons-css');
    wp_dequeue_style('thickbox-css');
    wp_dequeue_style('contact-form-7-css');
}
add_filter('wp_footer', 'remove_unwanted_css');
```

As you can see, I tried both "deregister" and "dequeue", but the CSS files keeps loading. I cleared every possible cache.

This is from my source file when I load the website (www.bmpaints.co.il)

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://www.bmpaints.co.il/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.5.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='thickbox-css'  href='http://www.bmpaints.co.il/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=4.5.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://www.bmpaints.co.il/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.4.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

What am I missing..?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer), `wp_footer` is an action, not a filter.

Try replacing

```
add_filter('wp_footer', 'remove_unwanted_css');
```

By

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'remove_unwanted_css');
```

---

You need to check which hook was used to register the styles that you are trying to remove. Then use the same hook to deregister the styles and set the priority to a higher number than the one that was used to register the styles. The default priority is 10, so try 11, if it was not explicitly set:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'remove_unwanted_css', 11);
```

If it doesn't help, try the hook [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_unwanted_css');
```

Comment: Try removing the `-css` suffix from the script names. It was probably added by WordPress.